# how to pass array from react native to php to store in database

Tags: php, reactjs, react-native

I am totally new in React native. i have this array data in my state. I am trying to send this array by using apisauce but it giving me error

```
Array [
  Object {
    "name": "king",
    "meet_date": "2022-6-25 18:37",
    "buy_fk": "17"
},
   Object {
    "name": "prince",
    "meet_date": "2022-6-25 18:37",
    "buy_fk": "18"
},
  Object {
    "name": "queen",
    "meet_date": "2022-6-25 18:37",
    "buy_fk": "19"
},
]
```

i want to pass this data to my server where i will store this array data to my database. and I am using codeigniter 4  restful Api

php code

```
 $couple= $this->request->getVar("mydata");
 foreach ($couple as $values) {
    echo $value;
 }
```

error

> "title": "ErrorException",
> "type": "ErrorException",
> "code": 500,
> "message": "foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given",

Comment: What is `$this->request->getVar()`? According to [the documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html), you fetch post data in CI with: `$this->input->post('someField')`. You should also post _all_ relevant code. The question is "how to pass data from react native", but you have omitted that code from the question.

Comment: in CI 4 we use getVar("somefirld") also to receive data , i tried to recive single id and its worked,  actually i want send array from react native to server but do not know how ?

Comment: So show us the code you're having issues with (the react native code). What debugging have you done? Have you checked what the `$_POST` variable actually contains?

Comment: how i can check $_POST variable ? am totally new sorry if i am asking stupid question, can you suggest any link from where i can copy how to pass array from react to php ?